# How can I make content area change on different requests?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I have a template like this.

```
<div class="content">
      @yield('content') //this area should load different files on different URI's
</div>
```

If I load `.com/register`, it should load `register.blade.php` at the place of `@yield.` If I load something else, it will load that view.

I'll define which file should be loaded in `Routes.php` with `Route::get();`

Full source is here for easier readability: http://pastebin.com/t2Md20r9 so you can see what I did so far.

What should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, just extend your layout in `register.blade.php`.

1.Put your template file in `views/layouts/master.blade.php`

2.In your register.blade.php put

```
@layout('layouts.master')
```

in Laravel 4

```
@extend('layouts.master')
```

on top.

3.Now use `return View::make('register');`

Comment: Its your template/layout file name, you can name it whatever you wish. But as I told in the first step to name master.blade.php :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in your Route.php file something like this:

```
Route::get('your_page', function() {
    View::make('your_page')->with('contentTemplate', 'register');
}

Route::get('other_page', function() {
    View::make('other_page')->with('contentTemplate', 'other_content');
}
```

And in your_page, do

```
<div class="content">
     @render($contentTemplate)
</div>
```